# I was going to say

Tags: past-continuous

> **Joe**: Y’know, I don’t think that people really appreciate their parents until they get older. I mean, at least I can say that about
>   myself. And I think it’s true of, y’know, here in America.
>
> **Kristin**: Yeah, **I was gonna** say in this culture, anyway. Yeah I can totally agree with that.

What does "I was going to say" mean here ?

Source: Real English Conversation (A.J Hoge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kristin says that when she heard Joe say "Y’know, I don’t think that people really appreciate their parents until they get older." she wanted to add that it's true to this culture [= not necessarily everywhere else], but then he finished and mentions that too. So she adds that to emphasise that particular point (it's true to *this* culture) and to say that if Joe hadn't finished his thought, she would have added that.

And for the record it isn't past continous, it's a "future in the past" expression, you can read more about it here: https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/futureinpast.html